# $\mathbb{S} = \{MX - XM \mid X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\}$ gives $\dim \mathbb{S} \leq n^{2} - n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Fix $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and define the vector space
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{S} = \left\{MX - XM \mid X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\right\}.
\end{align*}
Show that $\dim \mathbb{S} \leq n^{2} - n$.

Comment: Well, what do you think about the problem?

Comment: Still thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sketch of proof:** Define the linear map $T:\Bbb C^{n \times n} \to \Bbb C^{n \times n}$ by $T(X) = MX - XM$.  We see that $\ker(T) = \{X \mid MX = XM\}$.  By [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/122503/81360) or [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/123065/81360), we see that $\dim \ker (T) \geq n$.  By the rank-nullity theorem, we have $$
\dim(\Bbb S) = \dim(\operatorname{im(T)}) = n^2 - \dim \ker(T) \leq n^2-n
$$
as desired.